# Relations and Functions are they unique?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $Y = \{5, 6, 7, 8\}$. For each of the following problems, find a relation between $X$ and $Y$ that has all of the required properties.

$R$ is not left-total, not right-unique, not left-unique, and not right-total.

How do you find out or know when something is left left total, right unique, left unique, and right total. I have read that if something is right unique it is left unique and also that left unique is one to one function. Any hints on how to do this problem? Also how does one find $R$?

Comment: I presume that, if you have an exercise to solve, you have also a textbook or lecture notes to study with ...

Comment: See [Left-total](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Left-Total_Relation) and [Right-total](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Right-Total_Relation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

A relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$ is *left-total* **iff** :

> $(∀s \in X) \ (∃t \in Y) \ [(s,t) \in R]$

that is, iff every element of $X$ relates to some element of $Y$.

Thus, $R = \{ (1,5), (2,6) \}$ is an example of a relation between $X$ and $Y$ which is not left-total. If you consider $3 \in X$, there is no element $y \in Y$ such that $(3,y) \in R$.

In the same way, you can easily "manufacture" an example of relation $R$ not right-total.

See [Binary relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) for the relevant definitions.